# Java: Implementing a default super class that will set members for all subclasses

Tags: java, swing, awt

Example:

I want to make most of the Components have a certain background color and certain foreground color, and I want to change it if default Color seems off. Primary methods to achieve this are setBackgroundColor() and setForegroundColor().

Most plausible answer for me is:

```
public class DefaultComponent {
  private static final BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.GRAY;
  private static final FOREGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
  public static void setComponent(Component comp) {
    comp.setBackground(backgroundColor);
    comp.setForeground(foregroundColor);
  }
}
```

Is this the correct approach? Also is there a special name for such a construct, such as in Factory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your design suggests that you need an abstraction. The common behaviour of certain methods can be enclosed in the abstract class, and the specific methods will be implemented by the concrete classes.

```
public abstract class GenericComponent {
  private static final BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.GRAY;
  private static final FOREGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
  public static void setComponent(Component comp) {
    comp.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    comp.setForegroundColor(foregroundColor);
  }

  //here provide a list of abstract methods that each extension class will implement.
}
```

As this is an abstract class, it can't be instantiated. You will need to have at least one concrete extension, and create instances of that one.

Comment: Thanks.

Is using a static function in such a scenario a good programming practice?

Also Abstract is the word, thank you.

Comment: This is not a very extendable pattern. Say you want to be able to set multiple attributes. Because you use a class you can only apply a single style this way. You prevent any other extension.

Comment: A static method can always be used if you don't refer to the state of the class inside it(there is no `this` used). All these methods are seen as utility methods. In this regard your method is a setter, but it doesn't really set some internal property to the object.